# C programming & pointers

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

This code is for converting character numbers to integer numbers and works well. I can't understand several instances about **ascii_to_int** function code!! The first case is:

```
while (*str == ' ') str++;
if (*str == '-' || *str == '+')
    sign = (*str++ == '-') ? -1 : 1;
```

I see that `while (*str == ' ') str++;` is for removing the leading blanks from a string. But I do understand the third line: why should I use `*str++`? Why not use `str++` as two lines before? When should I use '`*`' asterisk in similar cases? Despite the fact that there may be no leading blanks in the string to get removed, therefore `while (*str == ' ') str++;`  never executes, so why again we can use `*str++` and not `*str` instead in the third line? I know that pointers point to a memory location too.
And second case is:

```
while (*str)
        if ((*str >= '0') && (*str <= '9'))
            *value = (*value * 10) + (*str++ -48);
        else {
            printf("\n warning: the <%c> is invalid character.\n", *str);
            break;
        }
```

Surely, we know that the first character of string always is a *sign* ('`-`' or '`+`') and that is never between '0' to '9' characters, so always `else` block must execute. My means is by this part:

```
else {
    printf("\n warning: the <%c> is invalid character.\n", *str);
    break;
}
```

I am seriously confused!!
Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void ascii_to_int(int* , char*);
int main() {
    int number;
    char s[10];
    printf("enter numeric string: ");
    gets(s);
    ascii_to_int(&number, s);
    printf("\n numeric value is: %d", number);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
void ascii_to_int(int *value , char *str) {
    int sign = 1;
    *value = 0;
    while (*str == ' ') str++;
    if (*str == '-' || *str == '+')
        sign = (*str++ == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    while (*str)
        if ((*str >= '0') && (*str <= '9'))
            *value = (*value * 10) + (*str++-48);
        else {
            printf("\n warning :the <%c> is invalid character.\n", *str);
            break;
        }
        *value *= sign;
}
```

Comment: `Why not use str++ as two lines before?` -- Because the objective is different.  Two lines before, the objective is to skip over leading spaces.  In the third line, the goal is to identify the minus sign, if it exists.

Comment: `so why again we can use *str++ and not *str instead in the third line?` -- That code is doing two things at once; it is checking for the negative sign symbol, and then skipping over it.

Comment: `Surely we know that first character of string always is sign` -- See my previous comment; we already skipped over the sign character.

Comment: Because character array variables *are already pointers.*  You don't have to convert them into a pointer like you do with `number`.

Comment: The *str++ expression increments the value of the str pointer and returns the character that it was originally pointing to. So here, if your array contains {'+', '1'}, the third line will evaluate '+' == '-', set the pointer to the position of '1' and then put the value 1 in the variable sign.